# Twitter timeline/stream without mentions + Hide mentions from specific account

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I've been using Tweetdeck for a good week now because I have to manage 2 accounts, but I run into some problems.

- Is it possible to create a timeline/column where you see all Tweets which aren't mentions. I follow quite a lot of people which mention eachother, I don't need those conversations in my Timeline.
- Is it possible to hide Tweets which mention you from a specific account? (Example: I mention my second account on my first account, this mention pops up in the "Mentions column" which is undesired.)

Can't seem to solve these two!

Comment: It would probably be best to divide your questions into two separate Question posts.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in Tweetdeck from what I've seen.  There was a website I used to use called Filttr (https://oauth.filttr.com/) that worked really well for filtering out tweets, and they did have functionality for blocking out replies.